# PHP - looping a result set

Tags: php, mysql

I am going nuts over a script which I've been doing for years now...

The following script executes fine both on my local and on my live shared hosting environment.

BUT

If I add another echo during the "while" loop, the server is giving me a 500 Internal Server Error & I don't have any error_logs :( (and no, on my local it still works fine!!!!)

Any idea why? this looks crazy for me... or I'm just tired now -.-

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY datetime DESC";
$result = mysql_query($select);
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while ($comment = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $comment["comment_id"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $comment["name"]; ?
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $comment["datetime"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $comment["email"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `>` at the end of the `<?php echo $comment["name"]; ?` line. That's probably the issue if you cut and pasted this code from the problem script. If not - what echo are you adding that causes it to fail?

Comment: sry for the late reply - that's actually a mistake when pasting.  The echo i'm adding are simply <?php echo $comment["ip"]; ?> for example..

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with your code then or your echo, so something else is causing the error. Is there definitely a field called 'ip' in the table (case sensitive)? If it still doesn't work I'd try to see if you can get errors to display on the page temporarily by putting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` at the top of your script.

Comment: hey Tim, sorry for replying back but apparently it had something to do with memory_limit's because I limited my query to get only 50 & it works fine while before I was getting over 2000 rows - nonetheless, thx for the help :)